# Want to get only match in grep

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, grep

I'm trying to use the grep command getting only the match.

I'm reading a XML file and I want to get URLs in tag location

```
<?xml>
<!-- ..... -->
<location>http://myurl.com/myuri/document</location>
```

I want to get only "http://myurl.com/myuri/document".
I made this:

```
curl http://mywebsite.com/file.xml | grep "\<location\>"
```

And I received the full tag:

```
<location>http://myurl.com/myuri/document</location>
<location>http://myurl.com/myuri/document2</location>
<location>http://myurl.com/myuri/document3</location>
```

Now I want to get only the URL
I made this:

```
curl http://mywebsite.com/file.xml | grep "\<location\>" | grep -oh ">.*<"
```

And I almost win haha

I received the URL with chars > and <

```
>http://myurl.com/myuri/document<
```

How can I get ONLY the match?
For example (this example doesnt work)

```
curl http://mywebsite.com/file.xml | grep "\<location\>" | grep -oh ">(.*)<"
http://myurl.com/myuri/document
```

I want to use the var in wget after this. Like `| wget $1`

Comment: This is just not what grep is for. Use `grep` and then pass the result to `sed`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution I can think of is sed:

```
... | sed -e 's/^>//' -e 's/<$//'
```

This will get rid of the pointy brackets stuck on the url.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-P` option on gnu `grep` for PCRE regex:

```
curl http://mywebsite.com/file.xml | grep -oP '<location>\K[^<]+'
```

Or using awk:

```
curl http://mywebsite.com/file.xml | awk -F '</?location>' '/<location>/{print $2}'

http://myurl.com/myuri/document
```

Comment: I'm receiving this error message. I'm using mac os X

"usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
 [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
 [--null] [pattern] [file ...]"

Answer (score 1):

grep with Perl regex:

```
grep -oP '(?<=<location>)[^<]+(?=</location>)'
```

Or

```
grep -o '[^<>]\+</location>' |grep -o '^[^<>]\+'
```

Or with sed:

```
sed -n 's#<location>\([^<]\+\)</location>#\1#p'
```

And if you want to download all these URLs, then:

```
curl http://mywebsite.com/file.xml | 
grep -o '[^<>]\+</location>' |grep -o '^[^<>]\+' | 
wget -ci -
```

Comment: I'm receiving this error message. I'm using mac os X

"usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
 [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
 [--null] [pattern] [file ...]"

Comment: @RenatoCassino Which grep command have you tried from the above two?

Comment: @RenatoCassino on some versions of os x you need to use the command `pcregrep` in place of `grep -P`

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get anubhava's version working so just experimenting I came up with the following – note that I've included the GNU version as I'm not sure if it's down to an issue with that.

I was a bit concerned about handling embedded XML tags in what was being searched for (probably not an issue with your example usage of location but looking at this as a more general problem). I also found I had to remove the `<location>..</location>` wrappers in the resulting text hence the two sed commands.

```
duck@lt-ctaylor-2:~/ateb/myx$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.24

duck@lt-ctaylor-2:~/ateb/myx$ cat tmp.tmp
<location><test>123</test></location>

duck@lt-ctaylor-2:~/ateb/myx$ cat tmp.tmp | grep -o '<location>.*</location>' | sed 's;<location>;;' | sed 's;</location>;;'
<test>123</test>
```